# Are events added through innerHTML recursive?

Tags: javascript

For example:

```
div.innerHTML='<div onclick="HelloMuffin()"></div>';
```

Let's say I then re-apply another `onclick` event to that **same** node again through `innerHTML`:

```
div.innerHTML='<div onclick="HelloMuffin()"></div>';
```

Will a new `onclick` event be added every time I run that code? What I mean is, would this essentially create a memory leak? (If ran enough times)

Comment: You're creating a new element so yes, it's a new event but the old one gets destroyed with the old element.

Comment: When you say destroyed, does that mean the old event is sent to the GC? In this case, this would most likely be bad practice right?

Comment: Why would something getting garbage collected be bad practice? There are other things in the example code that *are* arguably bad practice, like creating inline event handlers and re-creating elements that already exist.

Comment: Well, I just figured assigning these `onclick` events could be done a  more appropriate way without touching the GC. I've read that the more you can avoid throwing stuff in the GC, the better. (This code will be run quite a bit, that's why I'm worrying)

Comment: don't worry about any of it, browser are very good at doing what you demonstrate, and inline events are making a comeback as templates get smarter. (ng-click, onClick, etc). further, trying tp predict memory usage is very complicated; it's better to simply use a browser profiler to test your exact code while it runs than to speculate.